# Centre of non-abelian group of order $p^3$, where $p$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $p$ is a prime number and $G$ is a non-abelian group of order $p^3$, then what can we say about the number of elements in the centre of the group $G$, i.e. $Z(G)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:By class equation, it can be shown that  $Z(G)$ is non-trivial. Now if $O(Z(G)) =p^2 $,we will have  order of $\frac{G}{Z(G)}=p $,which will imply $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ is cyclic. But that will imply $G$ is abelian(Verify),leading to a contradiction. Then the only other possibility is $p$,since it is already given that  $G$ is non-abelian.

Comment: Do we have some method other than 'class equation' to show that Z(G) is non trivial?

Comment: I'm sure there are, but it's the easiest way.  To see that counting is likely to be involved in some essential way, note that there are infinite p-groups with trivial center.  But all finite p-groups have non-trivial center (by the class equation argument).

Comment: Note that the class equation argument is elementary.  All conjugacy classes have order a power of p, and the group is divisible by p.  Thus, if one conjugacy class has size 1, at least p-1 more must also be size 1 so that the sum is divisible by p.